# how do I not show Dalvik debug messages in Android log

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I see a lot of this:

```
06-19 17:29:11.911: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10028): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 729K, 54% free 3490K/7431K, external 0K/512K, paused 39ms
06-19 17:29:11.941: DEBUG/dalvikvm(10028): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed <1K, 49% free 3855K/7431K, external 0K/512K, paused 29ms
```

repeatedly in the log.  Is there a way to not show the Dalvik debug messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set a [logcat filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#logcat). You can do this graphically in Eclipse as well.